# Choose the coorect option ?..

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let S = $\{(x,y) \in R^2\mid -1 \le x \le 1 \text{ and } -1 \le y\le 1\,\}$. Let $T = S \setminus \{(0,0)\}$  be the set obtained by removing  the origin from $S$. Let $f$  be a continuous function from $T$ to  $\mathbb{R}$.

choose all the correct options:

1. The image  of  $f$ must  be connected .
2. The image  of  $f$ must be  compact.
3. Any such continuous function $f$ can be extended to  a continuous function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
4. If $f$ can be  extended to a continuous function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then the image of $f$ is bounded.

My attempts :  For  option a) $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$  is  connected  and $\mathbb{R}$ is connected as a continuous image of connected set is  connected..so it  is true.

For option b) $\mathbb{R}$  is not compact so it is not true, as the  continuous  image of compact is compact.

option C)  is  false  because  $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$  is not continuous at $0$
  so it is false

For  option D) is  True  because  continious  image  of  bounded set is  bounded

Is   my reasoning  is correct /or not corrects??

Pliz tell me   or give any hints/solution

thanks in advance

Comment: To disprove (b), you need a counterexample.  Actually, $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ will work here too.

Comment: Your reasons for B and D are fantasy.

Comment: For (b) your error in your reasoning is that although the continuous image of a compact space is compact, the continuous image of a non-compact space $T$ is not necessarily non-compact. For example if $A= \{1\}$ is a one-point space then there is just one function $ f:T\to A$; it  is continuous and its image $A$ is compact .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $T$ is indeed connected, and so $f[T]$ is connected.

b) needs a counterexample; try $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\|x\|}$, then $f[T] = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)$ which is not compact.

c) same counterexample; $(\frac{1}{n},0)\to (0,0)$ but $f(\frac{1}{n},0) = \sqrt{n}$ has no limit.

d) is correct; if $g$ were the extension of $f$ to $S$, $f[T] = g[T] \subseteq g[S]$ where the latter set is compact, being the image of a compact space $S$. So $f$ is bounded.

Comment: thanks  @Henno Brandsma

Comment: Can the function be extended  , if {$f(x_n)$} were  convergent to a single point in $\mathbb R$  for every sequence {$x_n$} in $T$ converging to $(0,0)$? @Henno Brandsma

Comment: @cmi Yes, this unique value would be a continuous extension to $(0,0)$.